# python csv writing from giant loop

Tags: python, csv

Good day,

I'm gathering data from an api, and trying to save it as a csv. The format that I'm receiving it is:

```
for title in titles:
   print(title.name)
   for data in title.data:
      print(data)

Title1
data1
data2
data3
Title2
data4
data5
data6
```

etc., (top first, bottom last, from a giant loop)

I'd like to make a csv so that it looks like

```
Title1 Title2
data1 data4
data2 data5
data3 data6
```

There is a lot of data, so I can't save it as a list and zip it. Seems like it should be a simple task but I can't find a solution.

Comment: is the data numbers or some form that is different than than title? like titles are always words and data is always ints or floats/

Comment: You should take a look at the csv module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: @Jacobr365 Titles and data are both strings containing letters and numbers.

Comment: @Uriel There are a lot of titles. Would I need to do that for every one?

Comment: Can you know the max number of columns and length of each string you may get ? If so a solution would be to create a huge file and write each piece at the right position in the file as they arrive. (eg Title1 would be @ pos 0, data1 @ pos `len(s)*1*max(ncol)`, data2 @ pos `len(s)*2*max(ncol)`, data4 @ pos `len(s)*1*max(ncol)+1`)

Comment: if the data is of variable length and there is too much data to keep on hand and write all at the end, you could write each `title` collection to a temp file (one per title) then at the end read all the temp files back line at a time to write into a single final file

Comment: @jadsq Yes, that could work. I may end up doing that if I can't find a more robust way.

Comment: If you transpose your output CSV, you can append to an existing file

Answer (score 0):

Following Maarten Fabré's suggestion, you can make your data receiving function as data generator:

```
import pyexce as p

...

def data_gen():
    for title in titles: # put your data recicving api code here
       yield [title.name] +  title.data


p.save_as(array=data_gen(), dest_file_name='result.csv')
```

Then you will have the data in result.csv as:

```
Title1,data1,data2,data3
Title2,data4,data5,data6
```

Then you can transpose it later:

```
>>> s=p.get_sheet(file_name='result.csv')
>>> s
result.csv:
+--------+-------+-------+-------+
| Title1 | data1 | data2 | data3 |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+
| Title2 | data4 | data5 | data6 |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+
>>> s.transpose()
>>> s
result.csv:
+--------+--------+
| Title1 | Title2 |
+--------+--------+
| data1  | data4  |
+--------+--------+
| data2  | data5  |
+--------+--------+
| data3  | data6  |
+--------+--------+
>>> s.save_as('perferct_result.csv')
```

Alternatively, you can consume it right away without transposing it:

```
>>> s=p.get_sheet(file_name='result.csv')
>>> s.name_rows_by_column(0)
>>> s
result.csv:
+--------+-------+-------+-------+
| Title1 | data1 | data2 | data3 |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+
| Title2 | data4 | data5 | data6 |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+
>>> s.to_dict()
OrderedDict([(u'Title1', [u'data1', u'data2', u'data3']), (u'Title2', [u'data4', u'data5', u'data6'])])
```